# add VMFS5 disk on additional datastore to VM using Perl SDK

Tags: perl, vmware

I posted similar question on VMware community site but with no answer.

Each of my VM's has one hard disk on nfs datastore

```
9  VirtualLsiLogicController=HASH(0x46f5bc0)
'busNumber' => 0
'controllerKey' => 100
'device' => ARRAY(0x520e190)
0  2000
'deviceInfo' => Description=HASH(0x520e148)
'label' => 'SCSI controller 0'
'summary' => 'LSI Logic'
'hotAddRemove' => 1
'key' => 1000
'scsiCtlrUnitNumber' => 7
'sharedBus' => VirtualSCSISharing=HASH(0x520de78)
'val' => 'noSharing'
```

I have to find an option in Perl SDK to add a new disk which is located on **another** datastore (Serial attached SCSI disk to each ESXi )

dsbrowse.pl --name vp-dscs1-sb1

```
Summary
Name             : vp-dscs1-sb1
Location         : ds:///vmfs/volumes/5309af02-0ba1ac70-e723-10604bb454c8/
File system      : VMFS
Maximum Capacity : 931.25 GB
Available space  : 930.2978515625 GB
```

I tried to use a **vdiskcreate.pl** , but it does not have an option to use a **different** datastore for a new disk and the script always creates a new disk on a the nfs datastore (where existing VM disk is located).

It's pretty easy to do such task with a wizard on VCenter but I have to run it ~50 times

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the new disk as part of a [ReconfigVM_Task](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.VirtualMachine.html?path=7_0_0_2_6_16_22#reconfigure). This allows for an option to set the filename of your new disk. This is where you will include the name of the datastore.

It's a bit buried in the mess, but take a look at [ReconfigVM_Task->spec->deviceChange->device->backing](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.vm.device.VirtualDevice.BackingInfo.html). This attribute subclasses to several different device backing options depending on your needs.

Hope this helps lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, the post actually was some time ago. I already solved it after digging into VMware API

Comment: No problem. Just thought it might be helpful for others as well. :)